# MVC 4 - Downloading localized files from resources, how to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, download, localized

I've been playing around with MVC and localization for a multilingual site. It so happens I also have localized downloads (instructions in different languages). I thought: a resource can also contain files, so why not place them there? Easily said and done, but my question now is: How do I extract the files from the resource file so users can either open or save them?

Do I use `ResourceManager.GetObject("filename in resource", what type will it be?)` or `ResourceManager.GetStream("filename in resource", what type will it be?)` and how do I return them as file?

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517567/download-files-from-resource-library-in-c-sharp-net) post but I'm not sure if this is what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. Didn't need the `ResourceManager` at all.

In my Controller:

```
public FileResult Download(string filename)
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = null;

        switch (filename)
        {
            case "Flyer Instructie.pdf":
                fileBytes = Resources.Resources.Flyer_Instructie;
                break;
            case "Flyer Front.pdf":
                fileBytes = Resources.Resources.Flyer_Front;
                break;
            case "Flyer Back.pdf":
                fileBytes = Resources.Resources.Flyer_Back;
                break;
        }

        return File(fileBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);

    }
```

And in my View:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(Resources.DownloadsInstructionText, "Download", "Home", new { filename = Resources.DownloadsInstructionLink }, null) %>
```