# Overwrite file with a file in the program's resources

Tags: c#, file, resources, overwrite, visual-c#-express-2010

I am having problems on overwriting a file's content from another file in my application's Resources. I tried using `File.WriteAllBytes(path, Properties.Resources.MyResource)`, but it didn't work. I know the file is there, it will never be nonexistent. What I need to do is simply copy the resource to the specified path.
My function that is supposed to work:

```
public void Swap(bool v) {
        byte[] file = Properties.Resources.Resource;
        if (v) {
            file = Properties.Resources.Resource;
        } else {
            file = Properties.Resources.Backup;
        }
        stateBox.IsChecked = v;
        string path = Process.GetProcessesByName("Process")[0].Modules[0].FileName.Replace("Process.exe", "") + "File.txt";
        MessageBox.Show(path);
        File.Create(path);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, file);
    }
```

Comment: Try adjusting the write/modify privileges of the file in windows. If you are hosting this site on a server, you may need to give write/modify permission on the file to the "NETWORK SERVICE" user before you can modify it programmatically.

Comment: It's not running on a server, It's running on a average computer with Admin permissions, yet it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See if the answer from this article helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864140/write-file-from-assembly-resource-stream-to-disk

Comment: It seems there's a problem getting the destination path, I edited the question so you can see my code. I saw this in some other thread, and yes, I'm 100% sure that there's only 1 process on that name running.

Comment: Are you trying to write to the process's application directory?

Comment: I am trying to write to the folder where the process is located at, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You may be running into problems if you are running Vista or Windows 7 they do not like you writing to the program files directory. See this [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VistasShowCompatibilityFilesAndTheScrumptiousWonderThatIsFileVirtualization.aspx)

Comment: Erm, more problems, it doesn't even reach the `stateBox.IsChecked = v;` line. EDIT: Or maybe I'm just changing the wrong value. That's supposed to check the box when true, right?

Comment: The code stops in the `if (v) {`...