# Run exe from resources c# with command cmd

Tags: c#

i Need install software with switch silent install

Example:

```
Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C msiexec.exe /i " + My.Resources + "eav_nt64_enu.msi /qb";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

So How i can add My.Resources in cmd command.

Comment: What is `My.Resources`? Do you mean that you store the exe inside your application resources and want to access it - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292?

Comment: If it is the case then this question is the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864140/write-file-from-assembly-resource-stream-to-disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract your resource to a temp file, if it a file or executable.

If your resource is just a string, you can add it directly to command line