# Exporting images from resource at runtime

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to export (save) images from the resource file at runtime? For example, if I use a set of images in my program, I have them in the resource file, but what if the user wants to be able to save that image and use it for other things... is it possible to put a "save image" button on a form for the user to save the image without me having to send them the image separately? Everything I have found in a search for this talks about the .resx file itself... I don't want to add/save/edit/update this file at runtime... I want to be able to export the files from it individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're going to want to do is find a **SaveSileDialog** control from the *Dialogs* group in your toolbox. Add it to your forms designer. This control will then appear in the bottom of your designer. Next add a **Button** (unless you've already done so).

Open the code of the button and add:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

This will open the SaveFileDialog we added earlier.

Open the code of the SaveFileDialog and add:

```
Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
    My.Resources.YourImageHere.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.YourFileTypeHere)
End Sub
```

Replace "YourImageHere" with the name of your resource, and replace "YourFileTypeHere" with the file type of your image(i.e. PNG, JPG, BMP, etc...). Documentation regarding a SaveFileDialog control can be found [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Now your application should save the image when a user presses the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can search inside your Assembly's Resources using the Assembly class:

```
Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream (YourResourceName)
```

Using this function you can retrieve the resource you need and save it with a **FileStream**.

Here some usefull links:

[Msdn Documentation Resource Reading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkkf2x4f(v=vs.100).aspx)

[Write file from Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864140/write-file-from-assembly-resource-stream-to-disk)

Comment: Thank you.... but... I am a self-taught programmer from way back in basic....  I have never used the Assembly class or the FileStream class... I can see and understand your Assembly class statement.... but... how do I then get this to the FileStream?

Comment: Dear @Hari_Seldon I'll give you some documentation from whitch to start studing.